# The checkboxes as buttons has a color they all change to when clicked, how to alter this?

Tags: vb.net

On a form the check boxes can appear as buttons, when these are selected, they change colour to a light blue, how to alter this to something else??

Comment: That is determined by the system theme, the same way it is for actual `Button` controls.  If you fiddle with the `FlatStyle` then you will be able to specify your own `BackColor` but you may well have to set it yourself in the `CheckedChanged` event handler.

Comment: Actually, I just tested and I didn't even have to change the `FlatStyle` property (on Windows 10 at least).  I just handled the `CheckedChanged` event and set the `BackColor` based on the `Checked` property. I used `Color.Red` and `SystemColors.Control` but you can obviously use whatever suits you.

Comment: By the way, that default checked colour that you're seeing is the same as a regular `Button` when it's depressed, which is what a that representation of a `CheckBox` is supposed to be: a depressed `Button`.

Comment: The light-blue color is a *theme* color, much like the way almost all controls behave in Winforms.  The theme is a user preference, notably getting harder to change in recent Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you require:

Start a new Form App

Add a checkbox to the form

Double-click the checkbox to generate the CheckedChanged event then use this code

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        CheckBox1.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
    Else
        CheckBox1.BackColor = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```